# Regex, how repeat group?

Tags: regex

i try to write regex for get only amount, from string, i do this, it's work but i want to optimise my expression, for exemple i have
125.250.230,55

this is my regew :

```
\d{1,3}[\,\.]{1}\d{1,3}[\,\.]{1}\d{1,3}[\,\.]{1}\d{1,3}
```

i want to write it with another form with a repeat group like, but it doesn't work for me

```
(\d{1,3}[\,\.]{1}){6}\d{1,3}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear from your example if you want to match always 4 sets of digits separated by a comma or dot, or a variable sets of digits.

If exactly 4 sets of digits use this:

```
(?:\d{1,3}[.,]){3}\d{1,3}
```

If a variable sets of digits use this:

```
(?:\d{1,3}[.,])+\d{1,3}
```

If you want to properly match sets of 3 digits, with variable number of digits at the beginning and end, such as:

```
  1,123,123.1
 12,123,123.12
123,123,123.123
1,123,123,123,123.1
```

Then use this:

```
\d{1,3}[.,](?:\d{3}[.,])*\d{1,3}
```

Explanation of regex:

- `\d{1,3}` - one to three digits (0...9)
- `[.,]` - followed by a dot or a comma
- `(?:` ... `)*` - followed by a non-capturing group; the `*` means zero to multiple repeats

  - `d{3}[.,]` - inside non-capturing group, expect three digits, followed by a dot or comma
- `\d{1,3}` - followed by one to three digits

Comment: Can you also explain why. Or is regex magic?

Comment: I added explanation

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the group in your **exemple** non capturing. See https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html

Here is your **regew**:

```
(?:\d{1,3}[\,\.]){3}\d{1,3}
```